# Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties multiple fields with Kotlin

Tags: jackson, kotlin

I'm having trouble using @JsonIgnoreProperties with kotlin. I need to ignore more than one property, and I see many tutorial/SO questions where, with java, usually you do something like that:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "p0", "p1", "p2" })
class Example(){...}
```

So in kotlin it would be:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = arrayOf( "p0", "p1", "p2" ))
class Example(){...}
```

The `value` field of the JsonIgnoreProperties interface should accept array, since it's declared in this way:

```
public String[] value() default { };
```

But the compiler complains and want a string, not an array. 
I can't even duplicate the annotation, so how should I do to ignore more than one field?

EDIT: Seems like it's a kotlin missing feature, implemented since 1.2 beta. it will be possible to use `value = ["p0", "p1", "p2"]` for annotations. Before 1.2 beta it's possible to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties("p0", "p1", "p2")`, no way to prepend the array with `value =`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) here, which is what the Java to Kotlin converter does with your example code, and also what Android Studio suggests as a quick fix:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = *arrayOf( "p0", "p1", "p2" ))
class Example { ... }
```

[image: The quick fix intention action]

This works because array types in annotation parameters get converted to varargs in Kotlin, so you could just do this if you're not using an Array from somewhere else:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("p0", "p1", "p2")
class Example
```